# Why is my @media moving when I enter margin widths on responsive page?

Tags: html, css

New to coding and web design and learning through Coursera. About to complete my first assignment but I cannot figure out why my last floating `@media` moves to the second line below the first element when it is supposed to stay on the top line. Row and `@medias` are built on percentages so I don't see why it would be collapsing. Any help would be appreciated! First time posting so if I need to submit anything else into this thread, please let me know.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-4 {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0px 30px 50px 30px;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
  <h2>Sushi</h2>
  <div class='section'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
  <h2>Sushi</h2>
  <div class='section'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
  <h2>Sushi</h2>
  <div class='section'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code can be found at https://github.com/brannanekins in the only repository I have. I have also included in my repository an image of the final result of the HTML after the last @media instance has dropped to the second line. Code below are excerpts, but I am unsure how to make this anymore clear.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. After that edit your question and include a [repro] for debugging details. Questions must be self-containing and not rely on external resources. Especially, GitHub is not a suitable substance to provide debugging details.

Comment: Your text is really confusing and misleading. This has nothing to do with `@media` and that is the completely wrong term to throw around here. `@media` are CSS commands to create different styles for different breakpoints or screens. What you actually asking is about the alignment of different boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the margin of your boxes. You add a margin right and left of 30px each. Means the element requires 60px more for the margins. 3 x 33% equal 99% + 180px width. SO you need to calculate the width as `100% /3 - 60px` for each element:

```css
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .col-lg-4 {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0px 30px 50px 30px;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 60px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
  <h2>Sushi</h2>
  <div class='section'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
  <h2>Sushi</h2>
  <div class='section'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
  <h2>Sushi</h2>
  <div class='section'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note, that `float` is the completely wrong method to align boxes horizontally next to each other. That is outdated since 2015 where you got a global support for `flexbox` and `css-grid`.

`float` is a property to float elements within a text block such as an image in a newspaper column. It should never be used to align elements in a styling manner (with exception of email templates).

Comment: Thank you very much for flexbox and css-grid updates. I will redo all my code to incorporate these tools!